# ElasticSearch Javascript, Highlight not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

we switched recently to ElasticSearch Angular version and everything is working as expected except the Highlight, which is not returned at all.

This is how I setup a demo query:

```
$esClient.search({
            index: 'myIndex',
            body: {
                size: 10,
                from: 0,
                query: query,
                highlight: {
                    fields: {
                        "_all": { "pre_tags": ["<em>"], "post_tags": ["</em>"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(function (result) {

            // map the resultset for Row Template
            var currentRows = result.hits.hits.map(function (record) {
                return {
                    "type": record._type,
                    "entity": record._source,           // the result
                    "highlight": record.highlight,      // the highlights
                    "id": record._id                    // Search record ID
                };
            });

        });
```

If I use the same code with a classic XmlHttpRequest and pass the query model inlcuding the highlight, I get back a JSON which contains an highlight array per each result, while using the ElasticSearch Angular client the query succeed but I don't get back the highlight.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to change to this format:

```
{
"query" : {...},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "fields" : {
        "_all" : {}
    }
}}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: I could not get results with this example.